# NPM crashes when I try to install packages from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

When i use `mikhail@MikhailPC:~/Desktop/restory$ sudo npm i` npm returns me `Illegal InstructionfetchMetadata: sill install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree`.

```
mikhail@MikhailPC:~/Desktop/restory$ npm -v
6.13.7
mikhail@MikhailPC:~/Desktop/restory$ node -v
v13.11.0
```

Comment: Could you show us your package.json file and explain why do you use sudo ?

Comment: there is no difference if i use sudo or no, the same error. package.json https://pastebin.com/CNYjyHib

Comment: What is your linux distribution and which Node.js package did you install?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, all of them ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the Node.js you are trying to execute is not compiled for the processor architecture of your machine.

Run this command: `uname -m` the result will likely be one of the following:

- `x86_64`: 64 bits
- `i686`: 32 bits
- Starting with `armv7`: ARMv7 (32 bits)
- Starting with `armv8`: ARMv8 (64 bits)

Remove your current Node.js and download the corresponding Node.js release from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ or any package manager (note that there is no release for Linux 32 bits).

Comment: One thing to one is that the last Node version for ARMv6 (e.g. Raspberry Pi Zero W) is Node 10. ARMv6 was [removed from releases starting v12.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/pull/2205).

Comment: I'm curious about the npm message. Could you explain what is the related problem with the Node.js version? npm error message doesn't mention an architecture problem.

Comment: Not an instruction set architecture expert, but I suggest that returning a version number as a string makes calls to few different instructions, so that can work cross architectures.

Comment: For which package in particular?

Comment: Not a package, Node.js binary which is written in C++, then compiled to machine language

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what is the exact problem in this context with npm according to a wrong Node.js architecture version? What is that "Illegal InstructionfetchMetadata" means? Why npm doesn't abort with a clear message on an unsupported arch?

Comment: Two messages are merged :Illegal Instruction and fetchMetadata. That means fetchMetadata has tried to execute an illegal instruction to the CPU

Answer (score 0):

try to clear the cache of npm with:

```
npm cache clean
```

then remove node_modules folder and `package-lock.json` and try again!